# How to add liner gradient to the text in tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

How to add a linear gradient to the text/heading in the Tailwind CSS ? Although I was able to add this to the background using this

```
<h2 className="text-4xl w-full text-white font-extrabold bg-gradient-to-r from-sky-500/20 to-sky-500/75">
       Welcome To <br /> My Personal PortFolio 
</h2>
```

But I am getting this
[image: get]

Answer (score 1):

I had figured out a way after an hour's hustle.

```
<h2 className="text-4xl w-full text-transparent bg-clip-text font-extrabold bg-gradient-to-r from-white to-sky-500/10 p-2">
       Welcome To <br /> My Personal PortFolio 
</h2>
```

[image]

Comment: The essential part is `text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-white to-sky-500/10`. It is also possible to use arbitrary values like `from-[#e5e7eb]` and color stops, e.g. `text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-400 from-3% to-sky-400 to-77%`

Answer (score 1):

Give in class like this

```
class:"text-base font-bold whitespace-nowrap text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-br from-yellow-400 to-yellow-500"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```css
-webkit-background-clip: text; /* apply background clip */
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

to make your text clip gradient

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
}

h2.gradient-text {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #09009f, #00ff95 80%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text; /* apply background clip */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="gradient-text text-4xl w-full text-white font-extrabold bg-gradient-to-r from-sky-500/20 to-sky-500/75">
  Welcome To <br /> My Personal PortFolio
</h2>
```

Comment: I don't want to use additional CSS, although I had figured out the solution and posted below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To summarize your answer. Tested in version 3.3.2.

You should add [`text-transparent`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color), [`bg-clip-text`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-clip#cropping-to-text), background gradient [classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#linear-gradients) (e.g. `bg-gradient-to-r`), [gradient color stops](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops) (e.g. `from-pink-500`, `to-violet-500`).

```html
<!-- Basic example -->
<span class="bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-500 to-violet-500">
    Hello world
</span>

<!-- Arbitrary color values -->
<span class="bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ef4444] to-[#0f766e]">
    Hello world
</span>

<!-- Color stops -->
<span class="bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-500 from-5% to-violet-500 to-70%">
    Hello world
</span>

<!-- More color stops -->
<span class="bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500 from-10% via-sky-500 via-30% to-emerald-500 to-90%">
    Hello world
</span>
```